# get model instance based on its m2m relation to a list of objects

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

How to get model instances of Filter given they should be m2m related to a given list of Tags?

```
class Tag(models.Model):                           
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    details=models.TextField(blank=True)
    parenttag=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,related_name="childtags")   

class  Filter(models.Model):
    tags=models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='infilters')
    parenttag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name = 'child_filters')
```

This must be a relatively simple question but I didnot get answer on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a queryset of `Tags` and you want to get the `Filter` objects that relate to them you could use [the `in` query lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
Filter.objects.filter(tags__id__in=tags.values_list('id'))
```

Comment: This returns all filter objects that are related to a subset of tags but I want only those objects which have all the tags mentioned. How is that done? @Timmy